# Rails3 ActionView TagHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actionviewhelper

I want to get output as html like

```
<div>
  <div/>
  <a/>
</div>
```

For this I wrote the ruby code as follows

```
content_tag :div, '', class: 'handle' do
  content_tag :div, class: icon, style: 'display:inline;' do
    link_to name, edit_path(object), :remote => true
  end
end
```

this results in `<a>` inside second `<div>`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the link code inside the inner div hence rendering inside.

In your code, the code block between the inner div would make the link to render inside. You need to bring that outside

```
content_tag :div, class: icon, style: 'display:inline;' do
  the link here should be outside
end
```